# What the documentation of Linux Programmer's Manual is documenting?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, documentation, glibc, manpage

I have worked with the manual page of the socket() in my Linux system and I was wondering what the functions it is documenting are belonged to.

For example, the function `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)`. Is the function part of glibc ? Is it direct part of Linux Kernel somehow ? The manual's title **Linux** Programmer's Manual.

I would love to get an explanation and clarification.

Comment: It's a Unix system call. `libc` provides the API that allows it to be called from C/C++.

Comment: You can usually tell from the manual section. `man socket` will show you `socket(2)` i.e. that it's in section 2 of the manual. See `man man` for a list of sections. Section 1 documents standalone commands, 2 is system calls, 3 userspace libraries (libc if one is not mentioned), and 5 describes configuration files on disk.

Comment: Are you basicly saying that manual displays the generic Berkeley's sockets API as it in any other Unix-like OS(and it's ```libc```) and the implementation is up to the machine ?.  For example, if I am using Debian when I will use that function it will use glibc(its libc) as the function implementation and Linux system calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***After my little research :***

The `C POSIX library`, which is the C standard library for `POSIX` systems, contains numerous additional functions to those of the `ANSI C` standard, most of them are dealing with the operating system for some extremely uses (multithreading implementation, networking(including any kind of communication(IPC for example))), users privileges manging, etc. )

The `GNU/Linux` operating system, for example, is compatible with the `POSIX`, therefore the `glibc` is implementing the `C POSIX library standard`(`POSIX` `libc`) which contains all its additional functions and headers with their Linux implementation using Linux's System Calls.

In our case, the documentation of sockets which introduce in Linux's manual page for developers belongs to the University of California, Berkeley (The developers of that form of sockets and modern networking in general). Because POSIX has "adopted" Berkeley's sockets and has included the header `sys/socket.h` in its C standard library the `GNU/Linux` system implements it either in its C standard library known as `glibc`.

Therefore, that sockets' documentation actually documents the `glibc` functions which are completely compatible with the POSIX's sockets functions which are compatible with the Berkeley's.

Thanks a lot for those who have helped!

BTW : Any other answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 groups of documentation for C functions in the man pages (see `man 1 man`):

- Library calls (All library functions excluding the system call wrappers;
  most of the libc functions):

  These are in section 3 of the manual pages.

  Example: `man 3 printf`.
  That page documents a function provided by glibc
  (or whatever C library you use).

  Note: it documents the glibc version of `printf()`,
  with all its deviations from any standard
  that may also define the function.
- POSIX function definitions:

  These are in section 3p of the manual pages.

  Example: `man 3p socket`.
  That page documents the POSIX definition of the `socket()` function.
  It may differ from the actual implementation of your system.

  Note: The POSIX documentation com in the packages
  `manpages-posix-dev` and `manpages-posix` in a Debian system.
- System calls with libc wrappers:

  These are most of the pages defined in section 2 of the manual pages.

  These functions are implemented by the kernel,
  and glibc provides a wrapper function so that
  you don't have to call it using e.g. `syscall(SYS_socket, ...)`.

  Example: `man 2 socket`.
  That page documents the kernel implementation of `socket()`.
  It may differ from `socket(3p)`.
- System calls with no libc wrappers:

  These are some of the pages defined in section 2 of the manual pages.

  Example: `man 2 membarrier`.

  These functions are implemented by the kernel.

  The manual page will note that there is no glibc wrapper,
  so you should call `syscall(SYS_membarrier, ...)`:

```
MEMBARRIER(2)          Linux Programmer's Manual         MEMBARRIER(2)

NAME
       membarrier - issue memory barriers on a set of threads

SYNOPSIS
       #include <linux/membarrier.h>

       int membarrier(int cmd, unsigned int flags, int cpu_id);

       Note:  There  is  no  glibc  wrapper  for this system call; see
       NOTES.
[...]

NOTES
[...]
       Glibc  does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it
       using syscall(2).
```